# Apply a function on diff - possible?

Tags: linux, shell-script, diff

I wonder if the following case is possible in Unix using the diff function.

Let's say that I have one line

```
1234 1 2
```

and one file containing

```
1234 2 3
```

1234 represents the pid, 2 the disk usage and 3 the cpu usage for example.
Is it possible, using the diff function, to 'merge' my line with the line in the file, and to apply a sum function on the fly to have the following final output? (pid being the merge key)

```
1234 3 5
```

(3 being the sum of 1 and 2, 5 being the sum of 2 and 3)

Answer (score 0):

no, `diff` cannot do arithmetic calculations, use `awk` as following:

```
awk '{ grouping_disks[$1]+=$2; grouping_cpus[$1]+=$3 }
END{
    for(indx in grouping_disks)
        print indx, grouping_disks[indx], grouping_cpus[indx]
}' file1 file2 fileN
```